# node-imap module receiving old emails in inbox

Tags: node.js, npm, imap, node-imap

I am using the node-imap NPM module and am fetching all emails from my inbox. It works perfectly when a new email is added, however when I delete an email from my mail client (Mac mail) and refresh the code, the node-imap module is still pulling this email in the inbox. For example, if I have an @icloud.com email and I delete an email in the inbox on my Mac mail client, it is removed from the inbox when I go to www.icloud.com, but when I load my emails through the node-imap module, the email is still there.

Please see below code.

```
router.get('/get-imap-emails', (req, res) => {
const { email, password, incomingHost, port, tls, accountType } = req.query;
let emailMessages = []

var imap = new Imap({
    user: email,
    password: password,
    host: incomingHost,
    port: port,
    tls: tls
});

openInbox = cb => {
    imap.openBox('INBOX', true, cb);
}

imap.once('ready', () => {
    openInbox((err, box) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        getEmails(box.messages.total);
    });
});

imap.once('error', err => {
    console.log(err);
});

// Custom functions
getEmails = messageCount => {

    imap.search(['ALL'], (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            imap.fetch(results, {
                bodies: '',
                struct: true
            }).on('message', (message) => {
                message.on('body', (stream) => {

                    // Code to process email with mailparser
                });

            }).once('error', error => console.log(error)).once('end', () => {
                imap.end()
                res.status(200).send()                    
            });
        }
    });
}

imap.connect();
});
```

Comment: These messages are possibly marked \Deleted, you may want to search for the `UNDELETED` criterion to make sure you don’t get these.

Comment: @Max Tried this a couple of days ago, worked straight away!